# AngularJS combine uib modal to a service

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I try to open a modal with the uibModal (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Fmodal) but I want to have one modal with custom text inside.

i'm trying to open the modal like this :

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: '/crims/thermofluor/experiments/components/modal.html',
    size: 'sm',
    controller: 'ModalController',
    resolve: {
        content: function () {
            return 'test';
        }
    }
});
```

With this controller :

```
angular
.module('thermofluor')
.controller('ModalController', ModalController)

ModalController.$inject = ['$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance'];

function ModalController($uibModal, $uibModalInstance, content) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.content = content;

  $ctrl.ok = function () {
      $uibModalInstance.close();
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  };
}
```

But it seems not work, angular says that ModalController is not a function (in the modal opening ), so what can I do to get this works ?

Edit : I can do that without a ModalController :

```
$uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title-bottom',
    ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body-bottom',
    templateUrl:  'components/modal.html',
    size: 'sm',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.content = 'bottom';
    }
});
```

But the buttons of my modal doesn't work

**Edit**

This finally works, here is how I do this :

```
function openModal(templateName, content, title){
    var template = 'components/modal/'+templateName;
    $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title-bottom',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body-bottom',
        templateUrl:  template,
        size: 'sm',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
            $scope.content = content;
            $scope.title = title;
            var $ctrl = this;

            $ctrl.ok = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            };

            $ctrl.cancel = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you didn't add `'content'` to your injection (`ModalController.$inject`)

Comment: even thou, it should not cause the error

Comment: Your $inject has two elements. Your ModalController function has 3. Besids you're using `this`, but you're not using controllerAs.

Comment: I add it but yea still my error, seems like my main controller doesn't know what is ModalController

Comment: You probably forgot to include the script for your modal controller in  your html page.

Comment: There are numerous possibilities which can cause this issue, but that's too broad to go through one-by-one in this forum. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and we will try to help you.

Comment: My controller is included with a ng-include in the html file

Comment: Maybe i can not use another controller for the modal ? Without another controller i'm able to set the content but I don't find how to make the buttons works

Comment: @Jessy you can't do that. All the controllers must be configured (added to the module) at startup time, before that application starts.

Comment: Look at my edit

Comment: If you solved the problem, write it as an answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: The injector array omits `content`. It should be: `ModalController.$inject = ['$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance','content'];`

Comment: I write my solution as an answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, here is what I do :

I create a service ModalService :

```
angular.module('myModule')
.factory('ModalService', ModalService);

ModalService.$inject = ['$uibModal'];

function ModalService($uibModal) {
   return new ModalService();

   function ModalService(){
       var service = this;

       function openModal(templateName, params){
           var template = 'components/modal/'+templateName;
           $uibModal.open({
               animation: true,
               ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title-bottom',
               ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body-bottom',
               templateUrl:  template,
               size: 'sm',
               controllerAs: '$ctrl',
               controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
                  angular.forEach(params, function (e, key){
                   $scope[key] = e;
                   });
                   var $ctrl = this;

                   $ctrl.ok = function () {
                       $uibModalInstance.close();
                   };

                   $ctrl.cancel = function () {
                       $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                   };
               }
           });
       }
       return {
            openModal: openModal
        };
    }
}
```

And I use it like this in my controller :

```
 ModalService.openModal("modal.html", {"content": "This experiment doesn't have a tm point", "title": "Tm Point"});
```

I can pass every variable I need and just set them in my modal html template